# How to affect specific element with jQuery toggleClass

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm doing a side-navbar, it has multiple link containers that are suppoused to be hidden until a click event happens on the link-title above it. The code is something like this:

```html
<div class="link-section">
     <small class="link-section-title">Utilities</small>
     <div class="link" data-type="accounts">
       <span class="iconify" data-icon="material-symbols:inventory-2-outline-rounded" style="color: #ececec;" data-width="20" data-height="20"></span>
       <p>Accounts</p>
     </div>
     <div class="links">
       <p>manage</p>
       <p>example</p>
       <p>example</p>
       <p>example</p>
       <p>example</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

When I click on the element `link-section-title`, I'm using jQuery to toggle a class called 'open' that sets a max-height to the `div.links`. The problem is that I have multiple `link-sections` and everytime I click on one `link-section-title` it adds the `open` class to every `div.links` in the page.

Is there some way to prevent this and only add the class to the container that is suppoused to open? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$(this)` to access the elements in the same section.

```
$(".link-section-title").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".links").toggleClass("open");
});
```